# Restrict access to apache2 web root but allow it to subfolders

Tags: configuration, apache2

I need to restrict access by password to my web root apache test server (ie http://localhost) but allow access to subfolders (ie: http://localhost/testsite)

I did create the .htpasswd and .htaccess, and put the .htaccess to web root (http://localhost) so when trying to access web root, it asks for user and pass, but so does  in subfolders (ie: trying to access http://localhost/testite)

I want to be asked for password on web root, but not on subfolders.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems like you told Apache to require a password for your web-root, but did you dell Apache to *not* require it for all other directories?

Inside your .htaccess (or in httpd.conf, they do the same job) you likely have something like what is below (add a pastebin link to your .htaccess file and I can make this exact):

```
<Directory "/www/private">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all

   Options Indexes
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Private Access"
   AuthUserFile "/www/private/.htpasswd"
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

But that will apply to all directories under that path as well. You'll need to explicitly tell Apache otherwise.

```
<Directory "/var/private/subdir">
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

You can use regular expressions with `<DirectoryMatch "regex">` to generalize this, just don't forget to guard against `asdf.com/subdir/../` expressions.

UPDATE: 
Also worth mentioning that although much of the documentation already has `<Directory[Match]>` directives there are also `<Location[Match]>` directives that are helpful in the case of symlinks on the underlying filesystem.

Comment: Hi, it worked!, now i'm adding a 
<Directory /var/private/subdir>
    Satisfy any
</Directory>

to every subdir i want to be accesssed by anyone.

Best regards

Comment: I'm trying this and it kind of works but I still get the credential dialog for the subdir even though the page is displayed. How can that happen?

Comment: @markus-tharkun Satisfy dictates the way Apache handles Allow statements and Require statements. "Any" means one of the two must match. If you don't have an "Allow from all" or similar, or you don't satisfy the constraint, then you'll have to perform the Require half (i.e., authenticate).

Answer (score 0):

In Apache 2.4 we can use the [LocationMatch directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch) and a regular expression.

```
# Require a password to access to the root path with or without a forward slash
<LocationMatch "^/?$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Options Indexes
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Private Access"
    AuthUserFile "/www/private/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```